# Wraps elements either way

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.single-post .post-content').not(':contains(.gallery)').find('.lightbox').wrapAll('<ul class="gallery"><li class="gallery-item">');
```

I want it to wrap only if 'gallery' not found, but it wraps either way, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your HTML and your desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains` selects the elements that contain a specific text not those that have an specific element, you can use `:has` selector instead:

```
$('.single-post .post-content:not(:has(.gallery)) .lightbox').wrapAll('<ul class="gallery"><li class="gallery-item">');
```